# SearchView DropDown popup не помещается текст

Tags: android, android-search-view

не помещается большой текст в подсказке к поиску в тулбаре, использую свой TextView, пробовал много вариантов с атрибутами (inputType = multiline  и тд), ничего не помогает, думаю нужно обратить внимание на сам SearchView.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нужные фрагменты кода:

```html
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_goods_list, menu);
        final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        searchSrcTextView  = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete)
                searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
        searchSrcTextView.setThreshold(1);
        searchSrcTextView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
        searchSrcTextView.setSingleLine(false);


        adapterFprCats = new AdapterFprCats(this,R.layout.txt_cat_view,mItemList);
        searchSrcTextView.setAdapter(adapterFprCats);

        searchSrcTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Cat cat = (Cat) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                searchView.setQuery(cat.getName(),true);
                result.setText(cat.getName());
                return;
            }
        });

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        return true;

    }
```

```html
public class AdapterFprCats extends ArrayAdapter<Cat> implements Filterable {
    private ArrayList<Cat> mItemList = new ArrayList<>();
//    private final static String [] options = {
//            "Apple","Mango","Peach","Banana","Orange","Grapes","Watermelon","Tomato"
//    };
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<Cat> mSubCats;

    private String mMainCats;
    public String getMainString() { return mMainCats; }

    private AmazingFilter mFilter;

    public AdapterFprCats(Context context, int resource ,ArrayList<Cat> mItemList) {
        super(context, -1);
        this.mItemList = mItemList;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final TextView tv;
        if (convertView != null) {
            tv = (TextView) convertView;
        } else {
            tv = (TextView) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.txt_cat_view, parent, false);
        }
        tv.setText(getItem(position).getName());
        return tv;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mSubCats.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Cat getItem(int position) {
        return mSubCats.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public ArrayList<Cat> getmSubCats(){
        return mSubCats;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if(mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new AmazingFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;
    }

    private class AmazingFilter extends Filter {

        private final static String DELIMITER = "+";

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            final FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            String request;

            mSubCats = new ArrayList<Cat>();
            if(constraint != null) {
                request = constraint.toString();

                //cuts the string with delimiter
                if (request.contains(DELIMITER) &&
                        request.lastIndexOf(DELIMITER) != request.length() - 1) {
                    final String[] splitted = request.split("\\" + DELIMITER);
                    request = splitted[splitted.length - 1].trim();

                    //save string before delimiter
                    int index = constraint.toString().lastIndexOf(request);
                    mMainCats = constraint.toString().substring(0, index);
                } else {
                    request = request.trim();
                    mMainCats = "";
                }


                //checks for substring of any word in the dictionary
                for(Cat s : mItemList) {
                    String s_str = s.getName();
                    if(s_str.toUpperCase().contains(request.toUpperCase())) {
                        mSubCats.add(s);
                    }
                }
            }
            filterResults.values = mSubCats;
            filterResults.count = mSubCats.size();
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterResults results) {
            clear();
            for (Cat request : (ArrayList<Cat>)results.values) {
                add(request);
            }
            if (results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

txt_cat_view

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:id="@+id/txtx_cat_name"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Comment: уберите `android:ellipsize="end"`, добавьте `singleline="false"`

Comment: Спасибо, не помогает